# how to email filepicker url files as an attachment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filepicker.io

I am working with file-picker. from front-end side user is filling a form and uploading files in it, which are stored using file-picker. on submit of users form I have to send him acknowledgement email with his files as an attachment. files need to be send as attachment and not as file-picker url in body. I am using node js. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: are you using a email service like mandrill or sendgrid to email?

Answer (score 0):

Filepicker does have a functionality like this, https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_ingestion/javascript_api/export?v=v1, when using `export` choose `Send As Email` option to send it as attachment.

Example code:

```
filepicker.exportFile(
    'https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/0lYRK93XSHKnKaQ6elRT',
    {
    mimetype:'image/jpeg',
    suggestedFilename: 'newFile'
    },
    function(Blob){
    console.log(Blob.url);
    }
);
```